# Detecting character encoding in HTML

Tags: html, http, character-encoding

I download an HTML page. The HTTP content-type header specifies one character encoding, and the page has a `meta` tag that specifies another. What's the correct way to handle that?

I guess 'correct' isn't the right word, since nobody follows the damn standards anyway... so what's the way that will cause me the least problems?

Comment: "nobody follows the damn standards anyway" ... sad but so true!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Do the same as webbrowsers do: use the response header. When HTML is served over HTTP, the meta tag is **ignored** when the response header is present. Only when the HTML is read from local disk file system, the meta tag is been used. This is also explicitly specified by [w3 HTML spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/charset.html#h-5.2.2).

> To sum up, conforming user agents must
>   observe the following priorities when
>   determining a document's character
>   encoding (from highest priority to
>   lowest):
>
> 1. An HTTP "charset" parameter in a "Content-Type" field.
> 2. A META declaration with "http-equiv" set to "Content-Type" and
>      a value set for "charset".
> 3. The charset attribute set on an element that designates an external
>      resource.

Any existing decent HTML parser in whatever language you use should already take this into account. According your question history you're familiar with Java, I'd then suggest to grab [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org) for this.