# Convert NSData webpage with unknown encoding to NSString

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, character-encoding, nsstring, nsdata

In my app the user can save web pages. After a request, I do:

```
NSString(data:responseData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
```

to convert my `NSData` response to `NSString`. But some pages have a `NSWindowsCP1251StringEncoding` encoding, or something else, and the function returns `nil`.

How can I detect the encoding?

Comment: this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5436507/653513 (about HTTP content-type header)

Comment: so i need to check headers first ?

Comment: i would. though it is still not 100% bulletproof. CP1251 page _should_ have `Content-Type: text/html;charset=windows-1251` header set.

Comment: yes, and other page has: "Content-Type": "text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, i solved this like:

```
var pageEncoding = NSUTF8StringEncoding
if responseHeaderFields["Content-Type"] == "text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1" {
   pageEncoding = NSISOLatin1StringEncoding
}
if responseHeaderFields["Content-Type"] == "text/html;charset=windows-1251" {
    pageEncoding = NSWindowsCP1251StringEncoding
}
```