# Correct encoding for body from Request NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape a web-page for some data and I managed to post a request and got the right data. The problem is that I get something like :

"Kannst du bitte noch einmal ... **erzÃ½hlen**, wie du **wÃ½hrend** der Safari einen LÃ½wen verjagt hast?"

normally **erzählen** - **während**, so Ä,Ö,ß,Ü are not showing correctly.

here is my code:

```
var querystring = require('querystring');
var iconv = require('iconv-lite')
var request = require('request');
var fs = require('fs');
var writer = fs.createWriteStream('outputBodyutf8String.html');


var form = {
    id:'2974',
    opt1:'',
    opt2:'30',
    ref:'A1',
    tid:'157',
    tid2:'',
    fnum:'2'
};

var formData = querystring.stringify(form);
var contentLength = formData.length;

request({
    headers: {
        'Content-Length': contentLength,
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    },
    uri: 'xxxxxx.php',
    body: formData,
    method: 'POST'
}, function (err, res, body) {
    var utf8String = iconv.decode(body,"ISO-8859-1");
     console.log(utf8String);
    writer.write(utf8String);
});
```

how to get the HTML body in with the correct letters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### **How do I find out the correct encoding of a response?**

I went to the website you are attempting to scrape, and found this:

[image]

And another character encoding declaration here:

[image]

This website defined two different charater encodings! ***Which do I use?***

Well, this doesn't apply to you.
When reading an HTML file from a local machine, then the `charset` or `content-type` defined in the meta tags will be used for encoding.

Since you are retrieving this document, over HTTP, the files will be encoded according to the response header.

Here's the reponse header I received after visiting the website.

[image]

As you can see, they don't have a defined character set. It should be located in the `Content-Type` property. Like this:

[image]

Since they don't have any indicated `charset` in the response header, then, according to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5436452/detecting-character-encoding-in-html), it should use the `meta` declaration.

**But wait**, there was two `meta` `charset` declarations.

Since the compiler reads the file top to bottom, the second declared `charset` should be used.

#### Conclusion: They use `UTF-8`

Also, I don't think you need the conversion. I may be wrong, but you should just be able to access the response.

```
request({
    headers: {
        'Content-Length': contentLength,
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    },
    uri: 'xxxxxx.php',
    body: formData,
    method: 'POST'
}, function (err, res, body) {
    console.log(body);
    writer.write(body);
});
```

---

***Edit***: *I don't believe the error is on their side. I believe it's on your side. Give this a try:*

Remove the writer:

```
var writer = fs.createWriteStream('outputBodyutf8String.html');
```

And in the `request` callback, replace everything with this:

```
function (err, res, body) {
    console.log(body);
    fs.writeFile('outputBodyutf8String.html', body, 'utf8', function(error) {
        if(error)
            console.log('Error Occured', error);
    );
}
```

All the code should look like this:

```
var querystring = require('querystring');
var iconv = require('iconv-lite')
var request = require('request');
var fs = require('fs');

var form = {
    id:'2974',
    opt1:'',
    opt2:'30',
    ref:'A1',
    tid:'157',
    tid2:'',
    fnum:'2'
};

var formData = querystring.stringify(form);
var contentLength = formData.length;

request({
    headers: {
        'Content-Length': contentLength,
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    },
    uri: 'xxxxxxx.php',
    body: formData,
    method: 'POST'
}, function (err, res, body) {
    console.log(body);
    fs.writeFile('outputBodyutf8String.html', body, 'utf8', function(error) {
        if(error)
            console.log('Error Occured', error);
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks Lars ! I've tried that and it didn't work, I've also tried other encodings like "Windows-1250" , "ISO-8859-15" but also nothing. I've tried the same POST request in Postman and I get the correct results.

Comment: I try it later ! but that's one of the best answers ever, thanks man !

Comment: @anoumaru No problem :) Hope it helps.

Comment: Sorry to tell you that but it didn't work, still shows "Kannst du bitte noch einmal ... erzï¿½hlen, wie du wï¿½hrend der Safari einen Lï¿½wen verjagt hast?"

Comment: what also confuses me is that the other classes in the body are showing correctly

Comment: @AnwarBenhamada Perhaps my edit will help you. Read the very bottom.

Comment: It doesn't show an error but shows always the wrong characters. but it's ok I'll try another method. Thanks a lot Lars!

Comment: Sorry I couldn't help. I have not had that problem before. :( But thanks for accepting my answer.

Comment: thanks, because all roads lead to rome, I tried it with another language and made it work with java and Jsoup in 15 min ! if there's anyone interested in how to make it there, just give me a sign :)