# How does the browser practically detect the HTML page encoding?

Tags: html, character-encoding

Let's suppose that an chracter encoding format called X exists (for example UTF-8), if I insert in the HTML file the tag `<meta charset="X">` and then I save the file, obviously, with the same encoding, how can the broswer read the file later?

I mean, how can the broswer know the encoding of an HTML page if, to get encoding, it *must* read the file? It seems a sort of loop.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detecting character encoding in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5436452/detecting-character-encoding-in-html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/charset.html#h-5.2.2, a browser gets the correct encoding from the Content-Type header field of the HTTP response. If this field is not present, the browser reads the HTML page until the META tag, *assuming all bytes were ASCII characters*. So this only works if ASCII is a subset of the actual encoding.